# onRequestPermissionResult is never called from Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement SplashScreenActivity, which will request all necessary permissions and then redirect to the MainActivity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.versionView)).setText(info.versionName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CAMERA) != PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_PHONE_STATE, CAMERA}, 200);
        } else {
            onPermissionsReady();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 200) {
            onPermissionsReady();
        }
    }

    private void onPermissionsReady() {
        new Fork() {
            @Override public void run() {
                ApplicationContext.getInstance(SplashScreenActivity.this);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have two issues with it:

1. The splash screen design does not show before the Permission request dialog and the screen stays from the android background with application icons.
2. When you agree with the permissions, the `onRequestPermissionsResult` is NEVER called and the application ends.

**EDIT**: I created a sample application here: https://github.com/knyttl/TestApp – it demonstrates both two issues.

**EDIT2**: This is what happens when i agree/disagree with the permissions requests - the application just ends: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhvhXcEJxLw&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem: the activity has noHistory=true, which leads to killing the application as described here:

[Requesting Android M permissions from Activity with noHistory="true" and/or showOnLockScreen="true"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151233/requesting-android-m-permissions-from-activity-with-nohistory-true-and-or-show)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should extend from `AppCompatActivity`.
2. Try to change the line:

   `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, CAMERA) != PERMISSION_GRANTED`

to

```
`if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.CAMERA)  != PERMISSION_GRANTED`
```

3. Move the code for checking permission to `onResume`. Or leave it in `onCreate` but delay it, for example with `Handler`

Comment: 1. I don't want to extend the AppCompatActivity as it provides the titlebar which I don't want to show on the SplashScreen. 2. I actually have this, I just shorten it for the demonstration.

Comment: I updated the source, tried to inherit from FragmentActivity, but no difference: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/31069be3091c7aab41006e2f5a3c5391

Comment: Check twice if you really have permissions granted. Because inside `onRequestPermissionsResult` the result is ignored. Maybe this causes the error.

Comment: But the exectuion never gets into the onRequestPermissionsResult.

Comment: And you are sure you are running on a device or emulator with API 23? Have you declared the permissions in Manifest?

Comment: I am runninh device with api 23. Tried 24 as well. Permissions are in manifest. The callback method just seems to be ignored.

Comment: I created a sample application, which demonstrates the issue here: https://github.com/knyttl/TestApp

Comment: Started your project on the API 23 emulator, it works completely fine. Asks for request every time it is started, because there are no `checkSelfPermission` method calls. But asks, and the next activity is shown.